# I got error in creating emulator using vscode, how do i solve this?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator

I created a flutter emulator in vs code. Then I removed it using android studio. Now, I try to create an emulator again using vscode, it says error: avd not created. It doesn't give any other error hints, only that. It gives an error:

[The error is given in right bottom corner: Error: avd not created.]

The image is given in link below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IjOT.png]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It only shows that error box at Right bottom while clicked in create emuator button, not any other error codes. However, using andrid studio, I am able to get emulator. Using vscode to create emulator is not happening.